# Independent t test for two proportions

Tags: t-test

I am doing a study where I compare male to female participants in 4 different age groups (0-20, 21-40, 41-60 and 61-80). I want to check if there is a statistical difference in percentage between the two sexes in the same age category.
[image]

I have been told that it is not good to perform t-test this many times as it increases the risk for type I errors. However, I thought that was only the case if I would have conducted the t-test many times on the same data, which I have not. I have conducted an independent t-test for each age category between the genders seen in the table.

Is there any problems with the t-tests that I have done?

Comment: Do you know the underlying N's the percentages are based on?

Comment: Hi,
Yes I do. 
For example: 
For females aged 0-20 the total N was 69 and G S I 02 was 1 (1/69=1.45%).

Comment: Then run a logistic regression on the complete dataset.  You will want to control for theory & EDC, as well.

Comment: I don't understand. I want to show if there is a statistical significant difference between the sexes within an age category (like I have done with the independent t test in the table above). How will a logistic regression help me?

Comment: You have, or can form, a matrix of 1's & 0's. Eg, for females 0-20, you have 68 0's & 1 1. Those 1's & 0's are your Y variable in a logistic regression.  Paired w/ them are variables for sex, age, theory & EDC. You fit a logistic regression of Y on those variables.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Would a logistic regression (as you are describing) be better than the independent t-tests that I have already conducted? Is there a problem with the t-tests that I have already done?

Thank you again so much

Comment: The t-tests don't control for other, relevant variables; the t-tests don't control for multiplicity; & the t-tests are a very inefficient use of the data.  It is possible that the assumptions of a t-test are sufficiently met by these data, but it is quite possible that they aren't.

Comment: I only have the variables sex (female/male) and age (0-20, 21-40, 41-60, 61-80).
I should also add that the percentages are percentages of total number of diagnoses within the group. For example, G S I 02 makes up 1.45% of the total number of diagnoses for the female patients aged 0-20. So I don't understand why I need to control for multiplicity.

Comment: Okay, maybe I misunderstood multiplicity.
However, is it really needed to control for multiplicity in this case?
I only compare the two percentages with each other to see if there is a statistical significant difference between the female and the male group within the age category.

Maybe I could mention the multiplicity problem in my discussion instead? And mention that since many t-tests were conducted, there will be a risk of significant difference between genders although it is not the case.

Comment: That's an awful lot of extra stuff. Use the raw data & fit a multiple logistic regression model. That's it & it's correct.

Comment: Would the logistic regression model then be used combined with the t-tests that I have done?
Because I am forced to use some kind of statistical method :)

Or maybe I could use the Bonferroni method?

Comment: The logistical regression model would provide you with p-values, if that's what you're asking. If you aren't very familiar w/ this, you may want to work with a statistical consultant.